# How to make a Facebook FQL query to select all friends who don't like a page?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to create an FQL query that selects all of my friends who are in the United States and that don't like certain Facebook pages. Ideally, I would like to return a select on the users friends with an exclusion to people who like Page X or Page Y.

Facebook FQL is very powerful but it is also limited on some functionality. For example, the "NOT IN" operator is not supported [Source [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519823/fql-not-in-equivalent-operator-like-except) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308473/fql-select-query-with-in-not-keyword/8310831#8310831)]. After doing some research, it appears there's a work around to mimic the behavior of this. The sources I posted have examples, but in short, a user can submit a [multi-query](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/) to select a group of people (query 1) who are not in another group of people (query 2) and return the result.

This is my FQL query so far, but it's not behaving how I would like. Any help or suggestions?

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_square, current_location FROM user
        WHERE current_location.country = 'United States' AND
        uid IN (
            SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
        ) AND NOT (
            uid IN (
                SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (
                    SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
                ) AND (page_id=40796308305 OR page_id=56381779049)
            )
        )
```

This should read: Select all friends who live in the United States and don't like Coca-Cola or don't like Pepsi.

Other solutions that I've seen is looping through friends, grabbing their likes, and just building my own data-structure by looping through that list. I could do that, but that is fairly time consuming amount of requests -- especially if a user has 2-4k friends.

Thanks for the help guys. It's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query seems to be correct. I think you missed out the permission: `friends_likes` that is needed to fetch the user's friend likes, in that case your last query-

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (
                SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
            ) AND (page_id=40796308305 OR page_id=56381779049)
```

will give you the less no. of results.