# Getting a list of Facebook friends while also excluding some

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the PHP SDK to make an FQL call to pull a list of a user's friends. It looks like this:

```
$all_friends = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY name ASC'));
```

This is working great but now I'd also like to exclude a few friends from the list. I've tried what I assumed would be valid but it appears to not be working (it returns with an empty list).

As an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
$all_friends = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND uid NOT IN (12345,54218,68151) ORDER BY name ASC'));
```

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: I think NOT IN" is not a supported feature of FQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"NOT IN" is not a supported feature of FQL. The [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) throws an exception : (#601) Parser error: unexpected 'NOT' at position 92.

You could do a simple select using IN

```
$all_friends = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY name ASC'));
```

and use PHP for filtering out using the ids.As far as I know it's the only way.

I found a related post: link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308473/fql-select-query-with-in-not-keyword/8310831#8310831).

Comment: Ah, ok, not the answer I was hoping for but the answer I suspected might be. Thanks for finding this for me!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the next FQL query:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (
  SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() 
) AND NOT ( uid IN ('13892588847', '10004291510061', '1000753466073'))
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Try it on the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).